# SQL Server Compact 3.5 gives Exception randomly in Background Process

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

As when I moved to SQL Server Compact 3.5 it gives exception in threads which are running in background and every time it gives me different exception as listed below..

1. `An item with the same key has already been added.`
2. `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`
3. `Attempted  to read Data when Datareader is closed`

This is very annoying for me as it stops my application suddenly..

Note that it occurs when my background worker or Task Scheduler is running in my application otherwise application works fine.

I don't know whether I am doing wrong or it is just because SQL Server Compact 3.5

Any help to solve my issue?

Thanks..

**EDIT**
Using Unit of work.

In main Thread , i am collecting 200 records from repository

```
UnitOfWork _uow;
ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Colloection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>;
ObservableCollection<ViewModel> AllColloection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>;

public Class()
{
   Colloection  = _uow.Contacts.Getall().Select(s=> new ViewModel(s,_uow)).Take(200).ToList();
}
```

In BackgroundWorker

```
AllColloection  =_uow.Contacts.Getall().Select(s=> new ViewModel(s,_uow)).ToList();
```

While collecting AllCollection it gives me exception as

`Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

initailly i want to display 200 records and when user click on next i am collecting next 200 records from Allcolloection.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're sharing ADO .NET objects (connections, commands, readers, etc.) between different threads without synchronization.

Either add some synchronization into your code:

```
private readonly _uowLock;

public Class()
{
    _uowLock = new object();

    // run any background threads

    // loading data in main thread
    LoadCollection();
}

private void LoadCollection()
{
    // obtain lock
    lock (_uowLock)
    {
        Collection  = _uow.Contacts.Getall().Select(s=> new ViewModel(s,_uow)).Take(200).ToList();
    }
}

// this should be called from background worker
private void LoadAllCollection()
{
    // obtain lock
    lock (_uowLock)
    {
        AllColloection  =_uow.Contacts.Getall().Select(s=> new ViewModel(s,_uow)).ToList();
    }
}
```

, or do not share ADO .NET objects between threads - they are not thread safe:

```
public Class()
{
    // run any background threads

    // loading data in main thread
    LoadCollection();
}

private void LoadCollection()
{
    Collection  = new UnitOfWork().Contacts.Getall().Select(s=> new ViewModel(s,_uow)).Take(200).ToList();
}

// this should be called from background worker
private void LoadAllCollection()
{
    AllColloection  = new UnitOfWork().Contacts.Getall().Select(s=> new ViewModel(s,_uow)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Please see my edited question and explain me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You're sharing `_uow` between threads. It's a wrapper over EF/Linq2SQL context, isn't it? Don't do this. It's not clear, when `BackgroundWorker` starts, but it seems to me, code in `Class` constructor and code in `BackgroundWorker` run simultaneously.

Comment: Any alternatives to do which i want?

Comment: @khushbu: one `UnitOfWork` instance per thread or synchronized access to the single instance from multiple threads.

Comment: BackgroundWorker starts from constructor of Class and then in main thread _uow collecting 200 records

Comment: @khushbu: this is exactly what am I talking about. Two threads work with the same `_uow`.

Comment: I understand what i am doing wrong but now i don't know  solution code.can give me solution code or links from where i can refer for single instance with multiple threads..